# How can I register opentelemetry lambda exention?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, open-telemetry

I am following this repo https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-lambda/blob/main/collector/README.md to deploy a lambda with `opentelemetry` extension.

I have build the repo and created a lambda layer by uploading the file `nodejs/packages/layer/build/layer.zip`. Then I created a lambda who uses this layer and added 2 env var:

```
AWS_LAMBDA_EXEC_WRAPPER = /opt/otel-handler
OPENTELEMETRY_COLLECTOR_CONFIG_FILE = /var/task/collector.yaml
```

I created a file `collector.yaml` under project root directory:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:

exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: debug
  otlp:
    endpoint: http://localhost

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [logging, otlp]
```

when I run the lambda I got this error:

```
2022-12-14T11:50:07.070+11:00   Registering OpenTelemetry

2022-12-14T11:50:07.098+11:00   Exporter "otlp" requested through environment variable is unavailable.

2022-12-14T11:50:07.122+11:00   2022-12-14T00:50:07.121Z undefined WARN Failed extracting version /var/task
```

it says `otlp` is unavailable. Do I miss anything? I am not sure what this mean.

Comment: Why you don't use ADOT (AWS Distro for OpenTelemetry)? It provides OTEL layer, so you don't need to build own layer. For example Nodejs: https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/lambda/lambda-js

Answer (score 2):

To enable OpenTelemetry in your AWS Lambda functions using custom layers; besides providing the two environment variables you described, you also need to add the custom layer to the function manually. You can do this using the AWS CLI:

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name Function --layers <your Lambda layer ARN>
```

You can use the AWS Console as well:

[image]

Keep in mind though, that you don't need to create a custom Lambda layer to enable OpenTelemetry. AWS provides different pre-built layers for you to use:

- [AWS managed Lambda layer for ADOT Java SDK and ADOT Collector](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/lambda/lambda-java)
- [AWS managed Lambda Layer for ADOT Java Auto-instrumentation Agent and ADOT Collector](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/lambda/lambda-java-auto-instr)
- [AWS managed Lambda Layer for ADOT JavaScript SDK and ADOT Collector](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/lambda/lambda-js)
- [AWS managed Lambda Layer for ADOT Python SDK and ADOT Collector](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/lambda/lambda-python)
- [AWS managed Lambda Layer for ADOT Collector and ADOT Lambda .NET SDK (Manual Instrumentation)](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/lambda/lambda-dotnet)
- [AWS managed Lambda Layer for ADOT Collector and ADOT Lambda Go SDK (Manual Instrumentation)](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/lambda/lambda-go)

Comment: I believe OP may have attached the layer - ‘ created a lambda who uses this layer’ - but great point on the managed layers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's necessarily related to the custom Lambda layer.
I use the "AWS managed Lambda Layer for ADOT JavaScript SDK and ADOT Collector" with the default `collector.yaml` and get the same error:

```
2023-01-03T13:40:58.367Z    undefined   WARN    Failed extracting version /var/task
2023-01-03T13:40:58.373Z    undefined   ERROR   Exporter "otlp" requested through environment variable is unavailable.
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.